# Getting Babel 6 to work - Including "require('babel-polyfill');" does nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am trying to get up and running using ES6 code in my Node JS application by using Babel 6. I've written some code that uses an "async function" and an "await".

According to the docs here, http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/, it says to stick either `require("babel-polyfill");` or `import "babel-polyfill";` at the top of your application to get the generators included.

However, after transpiling my app with `node_modules/.bin/babel app.es6 -o app.js` and running it with `node app.js`, I get: `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`. I've tried sticking both options on the first line of my application, but neither works.

However, if I run my app with `node --require babel-polyfill app.js`, it works just fine. What gives? How do I make the import work?

(I don't really want to start my app with a command line argument because of other limitations.)

Comment: More recent versions of node have es6 built in and there is no need for Babel anymore. What version of node are you using? Are you tied to an older version?

Comment: Using v5.6.0. I may have worded my question poorly; is "await" and "async functions" ES6 or ES7?

Comment: Not sure try it out without Babel. Note that there is a popular async npm module

Comment: I'm currently using both Babel and the async npm module. Will those conflict in any way?